# How to get arrays from a normalised table that stores array elements by index?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, generate-series

I have a table storing array elements by the array they belong to and
their index in the array. It seemed smart because the arrays were
expected to be sparse, and have their elements updated individually.
Let's say this is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE values (
    pk TEXT,
    i INTEGER,
    value REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY (pk, i)
);
```

```
 pk | i | value
----+---+-------
 A  | 0 | 17.5
 A  | 1 | 32.7
 A  | 3 | 5.3
 B  | 1 | 13.5
 B  | 2 | 4.8
 B  | 4 | 89.1
```

Now I would like to get these as real arrays, i.e. `{17.5, 32.7, NULL, 53}` for A and `{NULL, 13.5, 4.8, NULL, 89.1}` for B.

I would have expected that it's easily possible with a grouping query
and an appropriate aggregate function. However, it turned out that there
is no such function that puts elements into an array by its index (or
subscript, as postgres calls it). It would've been much simpler if the
elements were successive - I just could've used `array_agg` with
`ORDER BY i`. But I want the null values in the result
arrays.

What I ended up with was this monster:

```
SELECT
  pk,
  ARRAY( SELECT
    ( SELECT value
      FROM values innervals
      WHERE innervals.pk = outervals.pk AND i = generate_series
    )
    FROM generate_series(0, MAX(i))
    ORDER BY generate_series -- is this really necessary?
  )
FROM values outervals
GROUP BY pk;
```

Having to `SELECT … FROM values` twice is ugly, and the query planner doesn't seem to be able to optimise this.

**Is there a simple way to refer to the grouped rows as a relation in a subquery**, so that I could just `SELECT value FROM generate_series(0, MAX(i)) LEFT JOIN ???`**?**

Would it be more appropriate to solve this by defining a [custom aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xaggr.html)?

---

*Edit*: It seems what I was looking for is possible with multiple-argument `unnest` and `array_agg`, although it is not particularly elegant:

```
SELECT
  pk,
  ARRAY( SELECT val
    FROM generate_series(0, MAX(i)) AS series (series_i)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      unnest( array_agg(value ORDER BY i),
              array_agg(i ORDER BY i) ) AS arr (val, arr_i)
      ON arr_i = series_i
    ORDER BY series_i
  )
FROM values
GROUP BY pk;
```

The query planner even seems to <s>realise that it can do a sorted merge `JOIN` on the sorted `series_i` and `arr_i`</s>, although I need to put some more effort in really understanding the `EXPLAIN` output. *Edit 2*: It's actually a hash join between `series_i` and `arr_i`, only the outer group aggregation uses a "sorted" strategy.

Comment: I don't think it can be done much better. See `array_agg` for a different way to do it. You won't get rid of `generate_series` though.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Without `generate_series`: `with t(a,b,c) as (values('a',1,1),('a',3,3),('a',4,4),('b',5,5)), cte as (select *, unnest(array_fill(null::int, array[c - coalesce(lag(b) over (partition by a order by b), -1) - 1]) || c) as d from t) select a, array_agg(d) as d from cte group by a;`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe See my edit, is this usage of `array_agg` what you had in mind? I wonder whether it is possible to write `array_agg` and `ORDER BY i` only once, putting multiple columns through `array_agg` and `unnest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be more appropriate to solve this by defining a [custom aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xaggr.html)?

It does at least simplify the query significantly:

```
SELECT pk, array_by_subscript(i+1, value)
FROM "values"
GROUP BY pk;
```

Using

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_set(arr anyarray, index int, val anyelement) RETURNS anyarray
AS $$
BEGIN
    arr[index] = val;
    RETURN arr;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;

CREATE FUNCTION array_fillup(arr anyarray) RETURNS anyarray
AS $$
BEGIN
   -- necessary for nice to_json conversion of arrays that don't start at subscript 1
   IF array_lower(arr, 1) > 1 THEN
       arr[1] = NULL;
   END IF;
   RETURN arr;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;

CREATE AGGREGATE array_by_subscript(int, anyelement) (
 sfunc = array_set,
 stype = anyarray,
 initcond = '{}',
 finalfunc = array_fillup
);
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f2b7f49da50e9b92548a1c48ad2edb55). It also has a nice query plan that does a simple linear scan on the `values`, <s>I'll have to benchmark how efficient `array_set` is at growing the array</s>.
This is in fact the fastest solution, according to an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` benchmark on a reasonably-sized test data set. It took 55ms, compared to about 80ms of the `ARRAY + UNNEST` solution, and is considerably faster than the 160ms of the join against the common table expression.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this qualifies as "simpler" - I personally find it easier to follow though:

```
with idx as (
  select pk, 
         generate_series(0, max(i)) as i
  from "values"
  group by pk
)
select idx.pk, 
       array_agg(v.value order by idx.i) as vals
from idx 
  left join "values" v on v.i = idx.i and v.pk = idx.pk
group by idx.pk;
```

The CTE `idx` generates all possible index values for each `PK` values and then uses that to aggregate the values

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=fedb9ff3ad0449005093e1c76d6e6487)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this is the slowest solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this qualifies as a solution (much better than my original attempt) so I'll post it as an answer. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34163623/1048572) I realised that I can indeed put multiple values in the `array_agg` by using record syntax, it only forces me to declare the types in the column definition:

```
SELECT
  pk,
  ARRAY( SELECT val
    FROM generate_series(0, MAX(i)) AS series (series_i)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      unnest(array_agg( (value, i) )) AS arr (val real, arr_i integer)
--                      ^^^^^^^^^^                ^^^^        ^^^^^^^
      ON arr_i = series_i
    ORDER BY series_i
  )
FROM values
GROUP BY pk;
```

It still uses a hash left join followed by sorting instead of a sorting followed by a merge join, but maybe the query planner does optimisation better than my naive assumption.