# PostgreSQL custom aggregate: more efficient option than array concatenation

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, plpgsql

Consider a custom aggregate intended to take the set union of a bunch of arrays:

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_union_step (s ANYARRAY, n ANYARRAY) RETURNS ANYARRAY
   AS $$ SELECT s || n; $$
   LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE LEAKPROOF PARALLEL SAFE;

CREATE FUNCTION array_union_final (s ANYARRAY) RETURNS ANYARRAY
  AS $$
    SELECT array_agg(i ORDER BY i) FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(x) AS i FROM (VALUES(s)) AS v(x)
    ) AS w WHERE i IS NOT NULL;
  $$
  LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE LEAKPROOF PARALLEL SAFE;

CREATE AGGREGATE array_union (ANYARRAY) (
  SFUNC = array_union_step,
  STYPE = ANYARRAY,
  FINALFUNC = array_union_final,
  INITCOND = '{}',
  PARALLEL = SAFE
);
```

As I understand it, array concatenation in PostgreSQL copies all the elements of both inputs into a new array, so this is quadratic in the *total* number of elements (before deduplication).  Is there a more efficient alternative without writing extension code in C?  (Specifically, using either LANGUAGE SQL or LANGUAGE plpgsql.)  For instance, maybe it's possible for the step function to take and return a set of rows somehow?

---

An example of the kind of data this needs to be able to process:

```
create temp table demo (tag int, values text[]);
insert into demo values
   (1, '{"a", "b"}'),
   (2, '{"c", "d"}'),
   (1, '{"a"}'),
   (2, '{"c", "e", "f"}');

select tag, array_union(values) from demo group by tag;
 tag | array_union 
-----+-------------
   2 | {c,d,e,f}
   1 | {a,b}
```

Note in particular that the built-in `array_agg` *cannot* be used with this data, because the arrays are not all the same length:

```
select tag, array_agg(values) from demo group by tag;
ERROR:  cannot accumulate arrays of different dimensionality
```

Answer (score 2):

Array concatenation is expensive. That's why build-in `array_agg()` uses the internal `array builder` structure. Unfortunately, you cannot use this API on the SQL level.

I don't think using temp tables for custom aggregation is correct. Creating and dropping tables is expensive (temp table too) or very expensive (with high frequency), `INSERT` and `SELECT` is expensive, too. (Tables have a much more complex format than arrays.) If you need really fast aggregation, then write a C functions and use the `array builder`.

If you cannot use your own C extension, then use the built-in `array_agg()` function with deduplication and sort on already aggregated data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_distinct(anyarray)
RETURNS anyarray AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT v FROM unnest($1) u(v) WHERE v IS NOT NULL ORDER BY v);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Call:

```
SELECT ..., array_distinct(array_agg(somecolumn)) FROM tab;
```

Comment: Or just `LANGUAGE sql`? With `PARALLEL SAFE`?

Comment: I'm curious, is it only array concatenation or also array indexed assignment that is slow? Could [this aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58098627/1048572) be improved by an `array_builder` as well?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me, because `array_agg(somecolumn)` is only valid when `somecolumn` has a *scalar* type (`anyelement` in pg-ese) or when all the arrays in `somecolumn` have exactly the same dimensions. I have a column of 1D arrays of *variable* length.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - yes, it is possible too, and it is faster

Comment: @zwol - array_agg can aggregate arrays too. Just you need Postgres 9.5 and higher. But if cannot to use array_agg, then you need to write own C function.

Comment: @Bergi - string concatenation is similar - string_agg use own variant of string builder.

Comment: @PavelStehule I'm using Postgres 12.2 and `array_agg` does _not_ accept arrays that aren't all the same length.  See the example data I just added to the question.

Comment: @zwol - aha -yes, there is this limit. Then you need to write own function in C

Comment: Let me be clear that the question is specifically how do I do this _without_ dropping down to C.  I appreciate your answer, though, it has clarified my understanding of the problem and may be useful to other people even if it isn't useful to me.

Comment: @zwol - I am sorry, there is not any other way