# How to aggregate values in two columns in multiple records into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am on MS SQL Server.

I have a few records like this:

```
id   |   firstname     | startpoint   | endpoint   |    lastname     
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |   james         |  A           |   B        |    bond         
2    |   james         |  B           |   C        |    bond         
3    |   james         |  X           |   Z        |    bond
```

the only difference between these records are startpoint and endpoint

I would like to see something like this:

```
firstname      | startAndEndPoint    | lastname
-------------------------------------------------
james          | A, B, C, X, Z       | bond
```

I've tried `select concat(startpoint, ', ', endpoint) as startAndEndPoint from table where lastname = 'bond'` but it still gives me the result like this:

```
firstname     | startAndEndPoint    | lastname
james         | A, B                | bond
james         | B, C                | bond
james         | X, Z                | bond
```

I believe array_agg() function can help me according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163209/postgres-aggregate-two-columns-into-one-item) but it appears that function is available in postgres, not sql server.

Comment: What if Mr. Bond had a third row with `X` and `Z`... Would that constitute a separate rows in the result?

Comment: @TheImpaler the only difference between these two rows is the id, startpoint and endpoint. every other column is the same. 

If Mr. Bond had a third row with X, and Z, the startAndEndPoint would look like A,B,C,X,Z. Updated the question to reflect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpivot and aggregate:

```
select firstname, lastname, string_agg(pt, ', ') as points
from (select t.*, v.pt,
             row_number() over (partition by firstname, lastname, pt order by pt) as seqnum
      from t cross apply
           (values (t.startpoint), (t.endpoint)) as v(pt)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by firstname, lastname;
```

Unfortunately, `string_agg()` doesn't support `distinct`.  However, this is easily remedied by using `row_number()`.

Edit:

If you wanted to identify each separate connected component, then you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id, firstname, lastname,
             convert(varchar(max), concat(startpoint, ', ', endpoint)) as points,
             endpoint
      from t
      where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.endpoint = t.startpoint)
      union all
      select cte.id, cte.firstname, cte.lastname,
             concat(cte.point, ', ', cte.endpoint), t.endpoint
      from cte join
           t
           on t.startpoint = cte.endpoint and t.id = cte.id
    )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4a174be2774613bba8690d16ff2ba46a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: dang it, i made a bad assumption -- one other (update_datetime) column values are different. :( your query is probably returning an empty result, maybe due to the update_datetime being different

Comment: @thetinybeaker . . . The query works fine and answers the question that you asked.  I have included a db<>fiddle illustrating this.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question if you need to modify the problem.

Comment: Ah, I just fiddled with the db fiddle, it still works!!! Thank you so much.