# In postgres/presto/AWS-Athena, what's the opposite of `array_agg( (col1, col2) )` to get multiple rows per group?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34163623) shows how to collapse several columns per group to one array of key:value pairs.

```
friends_map:
=================================
user_id    friend_id    confirmed
=================================
1          2            true
1          3            false
2          1            true
2          3            true
1          4            false
```

```sql
SELECT user_id, array_agg((friend_id, confirmed)) as friends
FROM friend_map
WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP BY user_id
```

returns

```
user_id |           friends            
--------+--------------------------------
      1 | {"(2,true)","(3,false)","(4,false)"}
```

### My question

How to go the other way around, from the result table back to the initial table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PrestoSQL/Trino you can use [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(user_id, friend_id, confirmed) as(
    values (1, 2, true),
    (1, 3, false),
    (2, 1, true),
    (2, 3, true),
    (1, 4, false)
),
friend_map as (
    SELECT user_id, array_agg((friend_id, confirmed)) as friends
    FROM dataset
    GROUP BY user_id
)

-- query
select user_id, friend_id, confirmed
from friend_map,
unnest(friends) as t(friend_id, confirmed);
```

**UPD**

It seems that currently Athena (do not have access to Athena ATM to test it myself) does not support automatic unnest of rows to columns so you can try:

```sql
select user_id, r.friend_id, r.confirmed 
from (
    select user_id, cast(r as row(friend_id INT, confirmed VARCHAR))) r
    from friend_map,
    unnest(friends) as t(r)
);
```

or

```sql
select user_id, r[1] friend_id, r[2] confirmed
from friend_map,
unnest(friends) as t(r)
```

P.S.

Note that Athena is not based on PostgreSQL, it is based on Presto/Trino (dependent on the [engine version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions.html))

Comment: Thanks. However, running this on Athena I get an error: _MISMATCHED_COLUMN_ALIASES: Column alias list has 2 entries but 't' has 1 columns available_

Comment: @Emman yes, there is possibility of different `ROW` type handling in Athena and Trino (which I used and where the query works). Try `unnest(friends) as t(r)` and `select user_id, r`. If this works then you can try  `select user_id, r.friend_id, r.friend_id`

Comment: @Emman BTW what engine version are you running on?

Comment: I'm using version 3

Comment: So far, `select user_id, r from friend_map, unnest(friends) as t(r)` works. It gives a dictionary (curly braces) in each cell of `r`. However, `select user_id, r.friend_id, r.friend_id from friend_map, unnest(friends) as t(r)` results in an error :/  _COLUMN_NOT_FOUND: Column 'r.friend_id' cannot be resolved or requester is not authorized to access requested resources_

Comment: @Emman what is result of `select typeof(friends)`?

Comment: `array(row(integer, boolean))`

Comment: @Emman check the docs for [`ROW`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/language/types.html#row) type, you might need to cast it (`cast(r as row(friend_id INT, confirmed VARCHAR)))`) to access fields. Also you can try indexers - `r[1]` (`r[1] friend_id , r[2] confirmed` or `r[0] friend_id , r[1] confirmed`, though access by index is Trino feature also).

Comment: Eventually I used index (i.e., `r[1]`, `r[2]`), and it works great, thanks!!